# Keep adding query results to datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have a dataset which contains two tables.  Table[0] gets filled with multiple rows.  I then need to iterate those rows and for each row run another query and fill those results to Table[1].  What is the correct way to fill a dataset with multiple rows within a loop?  Abbreviated code sample of where I am:

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sql = myquery1;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    da.Fill(ds, "Products");

foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   productID = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ProductID"].ToString();

   if (productID != String.Empty)
   {
      sql = String.Empty;
      sql = myquery2 where productID = 'xxxxx'
      da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
      da.Fill(ds, "ProductProperties");
    }
}
```

This fills the "ProductProperties" datatable on the first loop but doesn't add future results.  What's the right way to keep adding multiple result sets to the datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way.  You only need one query to populate the child table.  E.g.

```
Dim ds As New DataSet

Using connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here"),
      parentAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ParentTable",
                                          connection),
      childAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM ChildTable WHERE ParentID IN (SELECT ParentID FROM ParentTable)",
                                         connection)
    connection.Open()

    parentAdapter.Fill(ds, "Parent")
    parentAdapter.Fill(ds, "Child")
End Using
```

All you need to do is duplicate the parent query as the subquery for the child table.  You can even put both queries inside one data adapter if you want.  The point is that there's no need to loop through the parent records and execute a separate query for each one.

Answer (score 0):

You query should return two record sets

```
SELECT ProductId, Name
FROM Products

SELECT ProductId, Property1, Property2
FROM ProductProperties
```

Then you can read the data from the above query to a DataSet as follows. So you will get two tables in the DataSet with the results from the two records sets from the above query

```
using (SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString))
{
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
   {
    cmd.CommandText = "query";
       cmd.Connection = con;

    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
   }
}
```